# Can I cache WaitForEndOfFrame or should I use yield new everytime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically the question is: Will I get the same result as `yield new WaitForEndOfFrame();` or should I avoid this?

Caching: `YieldInstruction waitForUpdate = new WaitForEndOfFrame();`

Using: `yield return waitForUpdate;`

Comment: What results have you got from your testing?

Comment: Seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely can. It's really useful to avoid unnecessary memory allocations.